# how to place text input beside of chips in Angular

Tags: html, angular, input, mat-form-field

I'm trying to make the mat form field that can show tags, input and drop down like the design below but I'm not sure how to achieves that so can anybody help me out. I've tried different methods for a few hour now but still can't find a way to make it work. will be really appreciated if somebody can give me suggestion or help.

I'm just trying to place the text input to be always beside of Chips (maybe expand like what I have right now if user put a lot of chips) and also have drop down options (icon) on the side like the design below.

```
<mat-chip-list *ngIf="editMode">
    <mat-form-field class="form" appearance="fill">

        <!--show Tags-->
        <ng-container *ngFor="let chip of chips" class="add-tag-chip" (click)="displayTagInput()">
                <mat-chip [selectable]="selectable" [removable]="removable" (removed)="removeTags(chip)">
                    {{chip.tag}}
                    <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="chip.pending !== true && removable" matTooltip="Remove a tag">cancel</mat-icon>
                    <mat-spinner *ngIf="chip.pending === true" [diameter]="16" mode="indeterminate"></mat-spinner>
                </mat-chip>
        </ng-container>

        <!--Text Input (supposed to be on the side of Tags)-->
            <input matInput [(ngModel)]="tagIn" [matAutocomplete]="auto" placeholder="New Tag"  (keyup.enter)="addTag()" />

        <!--For Drop Down List-->
            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let tag of filteredTags | async" [value]="tag">
                    {{tag}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>

    </mat-form-field>
</mat-chip-list>
```

This is the design I'm trying to do

[image]

[image]

This is what I have right now

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use it as it is represented in the documentation ? I also found [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/qdxrokeqakb?file=app%2Fchips-autocomplete-example.html) that is exactly what you want. Here is the html code :

```
<mat-form-field class="demo-chip-list">
  <mat-chip-list #chipList>
    <mat-chip
      *ngFor="let fruit of fruits"
      [selectable]="selectable"
      [removable]="removable"
      (removed)="remove(fruit)">
      {{fruit}}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
    <input
      placeholder="New fruit..."
      #fruitInput
      [formControl]="fruitCtrl"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto"
      [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
      [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
      [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
      (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)"
    />
  </mat-chip-list>
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let fruit of filteredFruits | async" [value]="fruit">
      {{ fruit }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Note that there is no `ng-container` ( they don't seems mandatory in your code) and the `mat-form-field` tag wrap the whole thing. In your code you have it as a child of `mat-chip-list`.

---

[Edit]: I got it. Here is the code :

.css :

```
/* ::ng-deep needed to only target your component (it's deprecated but have not replacement for the moment) */
.your-component ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-infix {
  display: flex !important
}

/* Change the placeholder to stick to the same position as if your input is focused, not really good */
.your-component ::ng-deep.mat-form-field-label {
    transform: translateY(-1.28125em) scale(.75) perspective(100px) translateZ(.001px) !important;
}
```

.html:

```
<mat-chip-list>
    <mat-form-field>
    <!-- ng-container is now a span -->
        <span *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" (click)="displayTagInput()">
            <mat-chip [selectable]="selectable" [removable]="removable" (removed)="removeTags(chip)">
                {{fruit}}
                <mat-icon matChipRemove matTooltip="Remove a tag">cancel
                </mat-icon>
            </mat-chip>
        </span>

        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="tagIn" [matAutocomplete]="auto2" placeholder="New Tag..."  (keyup.enter)="addTag()" />

        <mat-autocomplete #auto2="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let fruit of filteredFruits | async" [value]="fruit">
                {{ fruit }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>

    </mat-form-field>
</mat-chip-list>
```

Here is [the demo ons tackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pc4t62?file=app%2Fchips-autocomplete-example.html). Note that it does not work perfectly. I had to force the shrink effect of the placeholder with the css (I think it's because `mat-form-field` is inside `mat-chip-list`).

Also, since i removed some come to make it clearer, you will have to test it with your own code, chip remove methods etc.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I think I saw that example too but still can't fix it yet. I make child of mat-chip-list because I have Edit Mode and Not Edit Mode (didn't included). I also finding away to drop down icon on the right side that's why I'm posting here. If you could help that'll be awesome. thanks

Comment: Well please add a repro of what you currently have please, else we won't be able to help withtout all the needed elements.

Comment: Thansk for the reply, I really wanted to do that but I'm also using backend data so I'm not sure if I can add that on stackblitz. is there anychance you can look at the code and maybe spot the flaww. thax

Comment: @aaselab I edited my answer to give you what i could do. It's "not that bad" i think but the placeholder isn't perfect. You try to add some margin to the label or something. If you can the remove the css about `.mat-form-field-label`

Comment: thanks you so much for helping me out. by anychance do you know how I should implement the down arrow icon on the right of the input box so that user can click and view existing tags. thx

Comment: If by existing tags you means those that are in the autocomplete then you don't need the dropdown arrow since the autocomplete window pop when the input is focused. Also, I noticed a bug : when selecting multiple item, the input 'disappear' (become hidden due to too much item selected). A simple `flex-wrap: wrap` does not work so i don't know what to do about it. I HIGHLY recommand you to make your field works with `mat-form-field` inside `mat-chip-list`, else it creates too many side effect and you will always find bugs because of it.